# Running PHPUnit tests from directory with custom framework

Tags: php, jenkins, phpunit

For our project I have created a framework on top of the PHPUnit framework which helps us in some of the common tasks in writing unit tests.

This custom framework inherits from **PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase** and then modifies the mySetup() and adds bunch of useful functions for our code.

```
<?php

class OurUnitTestFramework extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public $dbMock;
    protected function mySetup (..) { ... }
    protected function testHelper () { ... }

}
?>
```

Now in our test code we just extend OurUnitTestFramework and then write the tests.

```
<?php 
require_once ("OurUnitTestFramework");
class DatabaseConnectionTest extends OurUnitTestFramework {
     parent::setUp (..) { ... }
     public function testSomeThing () { ... }
     public function testSomeOtherThing () { ... }

}
?>
```

Till now we were running all the unit tests through Jenkins and it still is running fine but now when we try to run the tests in a folder it fails. All the tests inside the folder/sub-folder runs successfully but there is one failure:

```
[sumit@dev model]$ phpunit database
PHPUnit 3.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.

F........

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 10.50Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) Warning
No tests found in class "OurUnitTestFramework".


FAILURES!
Tests: 9, Assertions: 30, Failures: 1.
```

I have a directory database which has sub directories and all the tests passes from that folder and its subfolder but I get failure from OurUnitTestFramework saying there is no tests found in this custom framework. So I am not able to understand why phpunit is running unit tests on the file which is included/extended in the test file?

We can simply choose to ignore this one error but I wanted to know if okay to leave like this or is there something that I need to configure to make it pass.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to run the tests in that file in isolation, without the other tests and with PHPUnit directly without involving `OurUnitTestFramework`. This may help isolate your problem.

Comment: I am able to run the tests in isolation but all my tests include `OurUnitTestFramework`. I can't take out this framework and use PHPUnit directly as it will require rewriting the tests again. Is there any other way? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make 'OurUnitTestFramework' an abstract class.

Comment: How will that help? Genuine question, not being sarcastic or rude, just curious.

Comment: That worked!! Can you explain why does it work this way? I am curious too. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Every unittesting class in PHPUnit must have at least 1 test, this is simply the error you got. Since this is not a real unittest, and just a baseclass it making it Abstract not only makes sense, it also makes PHPUnit ignore it as a unittesting class.

Comment: Thanks @Evert! I was trying to write one dummy test in this class so that it has at least one test but it was still failing. But making it abstract worked.